# Which conjunction is correct

Tags: conjunctions

You can watch tv ...

> A. After you have finished your work

> B. If you have finished your work.

Which option is correct?

Answer (score 2):

(A) is correct if the speaker knows the work is still going on.

(B) is correct if the speaker thinks the work may already have been finished.

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct. But "U" isn't a word, and "tv" is an acronym (i.e. should be "T.V.").

If this was some type of homework, I would make sure that this is the question you are being asked.

Comment: TV, actually an abbreviation, and is quite common without the dots.